# Changing opacity of button when pressed in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 RT app.

I have an image button on my page.

What I want is that when i press this button I either set the border to a yellow color or/and change the image.

I am trying to work out how to set this in the StoryBoard.

This is my markup ( I removed things that are not relevant like Grid..) :

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>                                    
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

and my button:

```
        <Button BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Name="btnDel" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background>  
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/del.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

Thanks

Comment: You have 'Storyboard.TargetName="Opacity"' which is a mistake since you don't have any elements named "Opacity" -- you need to target something in your control template that has an x:Name

Comment: HI, thanks for that info. Stupid mistake lol. If I want to target all my buttons on this page with this style then I assume I do NOT set the TargetName propery?  If that is correct then I have already removed it but I still get an error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name the element in your `ControlTemplate` that you want to animate, and then name that in your `Storyboard.TargetName` property (here I use the root `Grid`, creatively named **Root**):

```
<Page.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,12">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root" To="0.3" Duration="0"/>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
  <Button Content="hello"/>
  <Button Content="there"/>
  <Button Content="matey"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Changing the border colour is similarly easy. Changing the background image will be harder. If it is the same image on all buttons, then you can just hard-code that image into the template and switch `Visibility` on and off for it. If it is a different image in each button, it becomes trickier; a custom control (based on `Button` but with a `PressedContent` property) will likely be easier.

Here is a trivial sample (it "works", but isn't complete since there is no `DefaultStyleKey` and no template defined in **generic.xaml**, for example -- you must define the global style inside the app):

**MyButton.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace StyleTest
{
  public class MyButton : Button
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PressedContent", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyButton), null);
    public Brush PressedContent
    {
      get { return (Brush)GetValue(PressedContentProperty); }
      set { SetValue(PressedContentProperty, value); }
    }
  }
}
```

**MainPage.Xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="StyleTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StyleTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyButton">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyButton">
            <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,9.6">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <Border x:Name="Image" Background="{TemplateBinding PressedContent}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
              <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2.4">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <local:MyButton Content="change bg!">
      <local:MyButton.PressedContent>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Logo.png"/>
      </local:MyButton.PressedContent>
    </local:MyButton>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

The key here is that the `MyButton` control has a new property named `PressedContent` and the `ControlTemplate` uses a `TemplateBinding` to add it to the visual look of the button. The animation simply flips the `Visibility` on and off.

Comment: Wow what a comprehensive answer! Thanks